# How to set custom, uneven snap/tiling ratio on Windows 7+?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, window, default-settings

By default two active windows snapped side by side would fill 50% of screen real estate each:

```
+-----------------------+
|           |           |
|           |           |
|    50%    |    50%    |
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----------------------+
```

I would rather prefer to set another ratio deviating from 1:1 as the *default one* (without having to move the windows border with the mouse every time), for example I'd like to have a wider program window on the left, and a narrower one on the right:

```
+-----------------------+
|               |       |
|               |       |
|      66%      |  33%  |
|               |       |
|               |       |
+-----------------------+
```

Is it achievable by any means?

Comment: Interesting question. I have researched this a few years ago and didn't find an answer. There are some (paid) 3rd party utilities around that can "remember" the preferred location of application windows but most of those don't play nice with Windows 10 and all require a fair bit of finetuning to configure what to do with each possibly combination of open applications. I hope you get a good answer on this.